Why I observed two different signatures on my android aab package, when submitted it to Google Play
I am using app signature to verify my in-app resource. When I build the aab file with Android Studio and upload it to Google Play Console. There will be a procedure of auto test the App by Google. During this procedure, I recorded two different signature SHA-256 Value on different devices.One signature is what I saw on Google Play Console App Signing, The other one I haven't found where it comes from. I am using Google Play signing. It's quite strange there is two signature. Should there only one signature for my app? What is happened during this？
